# Null values in access vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

When I try getting data from Access db And there is actually an empty cell, vs gives me an error . I already tried "tostring()" method but It made thing more complicated

code:

```
     While reader.Read
        txtname.Text = reader.GetString(4)
        txtnotes.Text = reader.GetString(5)
    End While
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For VBA, check out the IsNull() function. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278616.aspx

So you would have something like:
`If IsNull(reader.get string(4)) then txtname.text="" else txtname.Text = reader.GetString(4)`

For VB, I would  do something like this: 
`If IsDBNull(reader.get string(4)) then txtname.text="" else txtname.Text = reader.GetString(4)`

For more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tckcces5(v=vs.90).aspx

You could also use the phrase `variable is dbnull.value` but it's a bit clunky.

Comment: there's no such predefined function in vb

Comment: Your title and the tags you used say VBA. Nobody will be able to help you if you don't provide accurate information. Please correct these items if you're actually using VB as opposed to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

```
While reader.Read
    txtname.Text = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.GetString(4)), "", reader.GetString(4)) 
    txtnotes.Text = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.GetString(5)), "", reader.GetString(5)) 
End While
```